# duvida outrocaso

Tags: portugol

Não consigo utilizar o comando outrocaso, gostaria de printar um erro quando fosse digitado um valor menor que zero ou maior que 12, porém, não sei como utilizar o comando outrocaso. se não me engano, esse comando outrocaso seria o default de C.

```
programa
{

    funcao inicio()
    {
        //variavel
        inteiro x

        escreva("\ndigite o número do mês: ")
        leia(x)



        escolha(x)
        {
            caso 1 :
            escreva("\nJaneiro")
            pare

            caso 2 :
            escreva("\nFevereiro")
            pare

            caso 3 :
            escreva("\nMarço")
            pare

            caso 4 :
            escreva("\nAbril")
            pare

            caso 5 :
            escreva("\nMaio")
            pare

            caso 6 :
            escreva("\nJunho")
            pare

            caso 7 :
            escreva("\nJulho")
            pare

            caso 8 :
            escreva("\nAgosto")
            pare

            caso 9 :
            escreva("\nSetembro")
            pare

            caso 10 :
            escreva("\nOutubro")
            pare

            caso 11 :
            escreva("\nNovembro")
            pare

            caso 12 :
            escreva("\nDezembro")
            pare

               outrocaso :
               escreva("\nVALOR INCORRETO!")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não seria `caso contrario:` no lugar de `outrocaso:`?

Comment: @anonimo Não conheço portugol o suficiente, mas é o equivalente ao `default` do `switch-case` do C. Tem a mesma nomenclatura e fluxo, inclusive, necessitando desses `breaks` no meio do caminho

Comment: Utilize ```caso contrario:```, veja mais sobre nesse vídeo:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQN3vZGKcp4